# Preventing presentation layer from directly accessing repositories?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

I'm trying to design my application in line with the "onion architecture" principles, and have something like the following:

```
HospitalController (depends on IHospitalService)
\
  --- HospitalService : IHospitalService (depends on IMedicalRepository)
      \
        --- SqlMedicalRepository : IMedicalRepository
```

My `IMedicalRepository` allows hospital data to be stored, but I have some business logic rules restricting how the data can be stored (for instance, either field A or field B must be non-null, and field C's format must match a regex to ensure that it is in a standardized format).  These rules are enforced in `IHospitalService`.

The problem with onion architecture and transitive references is that `HospitalController` must reference the project containing `IMedicalRepository` as well as the one containing `IHospitalService`.  So it's going to be possible for the `HospitalController` to directly request `IMedicalRepository` and store hospital data, bypassing these rules.  Is this just an inherent thing in onion architecture where you have to just remember not to do this?  Ideally, there would be a way of designing things where the presentation layer simply can't request `IMedicalRepository` directly as there's no design-time reference to it, thereby forcing it to go through the business logic of `IHospitalService`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking about strict or relaxed layered architecture?

Comment: I hadn't heard of those terms, but I guess I am.  Although having said that, I don't see much point in preventing the presentation layer from reaching through to get access to domain objects, so domain objects would be an exception that should be accessible by all layers.

Comment: Not necessarily. Let's suppose your entity has some audit properties (like CreatedAt, ModifiedBy, etc.) On the presentation layer you don't want to allow the consumers to modify them. Most probably your business logic won't rely on these either. So, separate models might be beneficial in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem with onion architecture and transitive references is that HospitalController must reference the project containing IMedicalRepository as well as the one containing IHospitalService.

That is not correct, it's not necessary for the web layer to directly access the data layer. I'll discuss the specific implementation later, but we first need to address whether we should be enforcing this to begin with.

### The rabbit hole of compliance

The issue here is a distinction on whether good practice should be expected to be followed, or rigorously enforced.
By that I mean that we're all in agreement that the controller shouldn't be referencing the repository as a matter of good practice, but not everyone specifically implements it so that it is actually impossible to do so, instead relying on the implicit expectation of developers doing the right thing and following good practice.

Part of the reason for not spending time on enforcing it is because you can never truly enforce it, and the more you try to approach a complete enforcement, the more overhead it requires (at an exponential rate).

By that I mean that when push comes to shove, a third project (business) **cannot** prevent one project (web) from depending on another (data). If the web project decides to reference the data project, it does not need consent from other projects to do so.

In order to block that, you would need rigorous access control between these layers, i.e. the web project developer shouldn't even be able to access the data layer's source code (or nuget package).
That bring a boatload of overhead with it. Other than the effort required to manage it all, it creates a lot of hurdles for developers to get over, especially when they're expected to develop features from top to bottom (database to controller, in this case).

If you have separate teams for the web project, the business project and the data project, then this becomes more feasible, as hardly any developer needs access to all layers at once. But this entails a lot of cooperation between separate teams, which is an overhead cost in time, effort, and risk of bugs/miscommunication. It also slows down development, as a change to the data layer needs time to permeate through to the business layer and then the web layer.

Most projects tend to not do this because of the overhead cost. Instead, developers have access to all the projects, usually in a single solution file, and are expected to uphold proper layer good practice. But the only thing holding them back from sullying this good practice is a stringent code review process.

---

### Increasing compliance

Having established that compliance is a spectrum that leads to a rabbit hole, you clearly seem to favor increasing compliance, even if not down the entire rabbit hole. So can we enforce more compliance than just blindly trusting our developers and their code reviewers?

> The problem with onion architecture and transitive references is that HospitalController must reference the project containing IMedicalRepository as well as the one containing IHospitalService.

What you state here isn't fully correct.

Your interpretation relies on the assumption that your top-level application (web, in this) case has direct access to all of the dependencies that need to be registered in the service provider. But that is avoidable, by delegating the registration responsibility to each layer.

It's easier to show this in code.

The simplest way of doing registration is by hardcoding it into the top-level application:

```
// in Web project

services.AddScoped<IFooRepository, FooRepository>(); // data dependency
services.AddScoped<IFooService, FooService>();       // domain dependency
```

But most projects tend to already segregate this registration to the project itself:

```
// in Data project

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterDataDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFooRepository, FooRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}

// in Business project

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterBusinessDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFooService, FooService>();

        return services;
    }
}

// in Web project

services
    .RegisterDataDependencies()
    .RegisterBusinessDependencies();
```

In the current example, the web project still depends on both the business and data project. You specifically want to break the reference between the web and data project, to prevent direct access to the data project's dependencies.

This can be done, but then you have to shift the responsibility of registering the data dependencies (i.e. calling the `RegisterDataDependencies()` method) to a project that *does* have a reference to the data project. Luckily, the business project still has a reference!

All you have to do to accomplish this is to have the business project's dependency registration logic call the data project's dependency registration logic:

```
// in Data project

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterDataDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFooRepository, FooRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}

// in Business project

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterBusinessDependencies(this IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.RegisterDataDependencies();

        services.AddScoped<IFooService, FooService>();

        return services;
    }
}

// in Web project

services.RegisterBusinessDependencies();
```

And this provides you with some reasonable protection against wantonly referencing the repositories directly. You can now remove the reference between the web and data projects. And as long as that reference does not exist, it's impossible for the web project to actually use the data project's repositories.

*Note that I've hidden some additional complexities, such as if the Web project has more than one dependency which in turn depends on the same data project. Those can be worked around, but you need to address some key concerns such as what to do in case one of those projects depends on a different version of the same data project, if that is a possibility in your situation. It usually isn't, but I can't exclude that with certainty.*

This is not perfect protection. Developers are likely still able to re-add this project reference.

This is where we get back to the rabbit hole. You could try to devise some clever enforcement making it impossible for developers to do this, but the benefits from doing so rarely outweighs the effort required to do so.

Instead, it's a lot easier to catch these kinds of errors during a code review process. While this does rely on the ability of the code reviewer to catch this, you should already be doing code reviews and those reviewers should already be aware of good practice rules like these.

Comment: Actually, my issue was that the web project had access to the repository *interfaces*, which are defined in the app core.  All it needs to do is request one of these interfaces and the DI will happily provide it with a concrete instance, so it doesn't even need to directly reference the data project.

Comment: @Jez: The same logic applies there. Only reference the project that houses the interfaces in places where you want to allow the interfaces to be referenced. In your example, that's the business project. Whether you separate your data interfaces and their implementations in different projects doesn't really matter in this context - the same logic then applies to both the data interface and the data implementation projects. If you house all your interfaces (i.e. business interfaces and data interfaces) in the same project, then you invariably make it an "all or nothing" kind of accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

**The big problem here is the `IHospitalService` contains business logic.**

The rules governing how data should be created and manipulated are called Class Invariants. These invariants should be enforced in classes that specialize in business rules, and business rules only.

A repository is a service in its own right — it is a **domain service**. The `IMedicalRepository` is a domain service for medical data that provides a layer of abstraction between SQL Server and the domain model. Repositories should abstract away data access. Repositories should definitely *not* implement business logic.

The `IHospitalService` object is a layer of abstraction between the controller and use case. It should not implement the kind of logic you describe, where one of two fields should have a value, or field C should match a certain pattern. Instead, it should coordinate the interaction between controller, domain model and `IMedicalRepository`. Services are the proper place to put logic that spans multiple layers.

The thing you are missing in between the controller, service class and repository is your **domain model**. The domain model should be enforcing that one of field A or B should be not-null. The domain model should enforce that field C follows a particular pattern (which might be a candidate for a [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object)).

Now it doesn't matter whether you use the `IMedicalRepository` or `IHospitalService` because those common constraints on data do not exist in the service layer. Instead, they exist in the domain model itself, and are thereby portable.

Pushing domain logic into a "service layer" results in an [anemic domain model](https://blog.pragmatists.com/domain-driven-design-vs-anemic-model-how-do-they-differ-ffdee9371a86), and gives rise to problems like you describe.

Comment: While I'm not claiming that your proposed solution doesn't work (it does, and I favor it too), there is a quite large shift involved from migrating from the simple Web > BLL > DAL setup to a domain-driven model. In the former, the services live in the BLL. Your answer seems to evaluate what a "hospital service" contains based on DDD definitions of services, but the question establishes a simple Web > BLL > DAL architecture. Again, the solution you use isn't wrong, but the answer initially comes across as disjointed because of unexpected assumptions of DDD that aren't in the question.

Comment: @Flater: I wasn't assuming anything about DDD. The point was that business logic should be in its own layer. I am open to calling it something other than "domain model" if that would clarify things.

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit I've never truly gotten my head around DDD.  Eric Evans's book is spectacularly verbose and boring, and I didn't manage to finish it.  I'd love to see a recommendation for a concise sub-200 page book explaining the concepts well.  I'm pretty sure there's no need for such length.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Just to clarify my earlier point, if you _don't_ assume DDD, then you can't reasonably infer that something called `IHospitalService` cannot/should not contain business logic, as the business logic itself can be interpreted as a service too (which generally is the case in simple Web > BLL > DAL setups, whose naming usually follow the "controller" > "service" > "repository" approach, just like the question seems to do). In DDD, the domain model itself houses the domain-specific rules, but that responsibility isn't explicitly carved out in non-DDD contexts.

Comment: @Flater: This is why I hate putting the word "service" in a class name. Anything can be interpreted as a "service". Service classes are the new "[something-Manager](https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/)". It's also why I qualified what a "service" means in my answer --- a thing that coordinates between the higher layers, data access and business logic. It's better thought of as a **use case** rather than a nebulous "service".

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for, but as soon as you can access an interface/class/whatever outside of a project (IHospitalService -> IMedicalRepository) every other project can access this too. Finer grained access-control is only possible within on project. So no one forbids to reference IMedicalRepository from the HospitalController-Project.

The only possibility would be to put IHospitalService and IMedicalRepository in the same project and set the visibility of IMedicalRepository to internal, but I guess that kills your layered architecture idea.

Comment: _" as soon as you can access an interface/class/whatever outside of a project every other **project** can access this too"_ While this may be a pedantic distinction, those projects require referencing the project that houses the interface/class/whatever. If you control the project references, you control the access to a project's public interfaces/classes/whatevers. That distinction, pedantic or not, negates the assertion in your second paragraph that the "only" possibility would be to use `internal` to regulate access control.

Comment: @Flater I think the author is not about "securely" preventing the access to the inferfaces, but more in an sense of self-protecting to wrong usage. Of course if you are in control of the project/source you could change things, but wanting to change such things sould be a warning to yourself, that you are maybe trying to do a modification that was not intended. So no offense, but the topic is a bit pedantic itself.

Comment: It just makes me laugh that people talk about "enforcing business logic rules" with clean architecture, and yet built straight in to clean architecture is the option to opt out of this by completely bypassing the domain services layer.  It seems like a pretty fundamental flaw.

Comment: @Jez: You're missing the part where enforcement comes in many different forms. For example, code reviews (and subsequent failures to pass the review) are a different way to enforce the same rule. They don't specifically disallow the code from being written badly, but they do disallow that badly written code to make it into the official source code. In cases where there is reasonable trust in both the ability of your developers to understand good practice and the willingness to follow good practice, strict enforcement usually isn't necessary and comes with a bigger cost than benefit.

Comment: @Jez: Think of it this way: there are two ways to combat people speeding on the highway. You can directly prevent it by installing speed limiters in all cars (which is what you're suggesting), or you can retroactively punish speeding by catching those who have been caught speeding (which is what most people tend to do). The latter is significantly easier to implement, and suffices when under the assumption of good will on the drivers' part.

Comment: @Jez think of it like this, if I'm writing code in an MVC view file, I can theoretically make database commands, call other webservices, etc. I can abuse the crap out of reflection in a lot of languages to get around internal/private classes too. There's no architecture that can stop you from writing arbitrarily bad code if you have the access to write the code.